# How to copy data from one row to another row linq?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I have a [Table] `Book` with some [Column] as `Author`,`AuthorCV`,`Editor`,`EditorCV`

and I have some value as :

1/ `Author` = "ABC", AuthorCV = "", `Editor` = "Haha", `EditorCV`= "Handsome"

2/  `Author` = "ABC", AuthorCV = "Pretty", `Editor` = "Teo", `EditorCV`= ""

3/  `Author` = "Tom", AuthorCV = "Cute", `Editor` = "Haha", `EditorCV`= ""

what I want is to copy the `AuthorCV` from not-null value to null value with the same `Author`
and the same with `EditorCV` and `Editor`

the result is:

1/ `Author` = "ABC", AuthorCV = "Pretty", `Editor` = "Haha", `EditorCV`= "Handsome"

2/  `Author` = "ABC", AuthorCV = "Pretty", `Editor` = "Teo", `EditorCV`= ""

3/  `Author` = "Tom", AuthorCV = "Cute", `Editor` = "Haha", `EditorCV`= "Handsome"

I have the Viewmodel like this

```
 public class    MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BookDataContext BookDB;
    public static string ConnectionString = "Data source=isostore:/Book.sdf";


    //****MainViewModel*****
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        BookDB = new BookDataContext(ConnectionString);

        if (!BookDB.DatabaseExists())
        {
            BookDB.CreateDatabase();
            BookDB.SubmitChanges();
       }
}
```

After try the answer:

I make a function as the answer below.... and when I run emulator...it has the error `{System.NotSupportedException: Method 'Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

```
public void copy()
{
BookDB.books.Where(b => String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AuthorCV) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.EditorCV)).ToList()
            .ForEach(b =>
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AuthorCV))
                b.AuthorCV = books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Author == b.Author && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AuthorCV)).AuthorCV;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.EditorCV))
                b.EditorCV = books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Editor == b.Editor && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EditorCV)).EditorCV;
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
books.Where(b => String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AuthorCV) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.EditorCV)).ToList()
                .ForEach(b =>
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AuthorCV))
                    b.AuthorCV = books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Author == b.Author && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AuthorCV)).AuthorCV;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.EditorCV))
                    b.EditorCV = books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Editor == b.Editor && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EditorCV)).EditorCV;
                });
```

Comment: I need put it in a public void. and what should I do?